# How to find Function or index of variables.

Tags: functions

So okay the questions says..... "Define the function of two variables INDEX(C,S) as follows: The variables C can be any single character; S can be any character string. INDEX(C,S) is the position in string S of the first occurrence of the character C. If S does not contain the character C, the value of INDEX is 0." Let S = "MISSISSIPPI" and T= "BULLETIN". now it says find INDEX("I", S)??? am counting the letters of I then S... Someone please explain thanks.

Answer (score 0):

INDEX("I", S) = "the index of the first occurrence of "I" in string S"

Since S = "MISSISSIPPI", we have  INDEX("I", S) = 2.

More examples:

INDEX("S", S) = 3,
INDEX("Z", S) = 0,
INDEX("P", S) = 9.

Comment: How are you getting 2 for INDEX("I, S) = 2